# Google Analytics database

Tags: database, schema, google-analytics

Does anybody know how data in Google Analytics is organized? Difficult selection from large amounts of data they perform very-very fast, what structure of database is it?

Comment: I guess most of the developers working for google singed some kind of non-disclosure agreement and are not allowed to talk about it.

Comment: The answers below are informative, but I'm still wondering how they organize that data? Are they using real-time map/reduce, or are all the scores already pre-computed? If the latter, again, how do they organize that, because the API allows for complex filters and grouping up to 7 dimensions?

Answer (score 11):

AFAIK Google Analytics is derived from Urchin. As it has been said it is possible that since now Analytics is part of the Google family it is using MapReduce/BigTable. I can assume that Google had integrated the old format of Urchin DB with the new BigTable/MapReduce.

I found this links which talk about Urchin DB. Probably some of the things are still in use at the moment.

http://www.advanced-web-metrics.com/blog/2007/10/16/what-is-urchin/

this says:

> [snip] ...still use a proprietary database to store reporting data, which makes ad-hoc queries a bit more limited, since you have to use Urchin-developed tools rather than the more flexible SQL tools.

http://www.urchinexperts.com/software/faq/#ques45

> What type of database does Urchin use?

Urchin uses a proprietary flat file database for report data storage. The high-performance database architecture handles very high traffic sites efficiently. Some of the benefits of the data base architecture include:

```
* Small database footprint approximately 5-10% of raw logfile size
* Small number of database files required per profile (9 per month of historical reporting)
* Support for parallel processing of load-balanced webserver logs for increased performance
* Databases are standard files that are easy to back up and restore using native operating system utilitiesv
```

More info about Urchin

http://www.google.com/support/urchin45/bin/answer.py?answer=28737

Long time ago I used to have a tracker and on their site they were discussing about data normalization: http://www.2enetworx.com/dev/articles/statisticus5.asp

There you can find a bit of info of how to reduce the data in DB and maybe it is a good start in research.

Answer (score 5):

[BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable)

Google Publication: Chang, Fay, et al. "[Bigtable: A distributed storage system for structured data.](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf)"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems (TOCS) 26.2 (2008):

> Bigtable is used by more than sixty Google products and projects,
>   including **Google Analytics**, Google Finance, Orkut, Personalized
>   Search, Writely, and Google Earth.

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume they use their '[Big Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable)'

Answer (score 2):

I can't know exactly how they implement it.
But because I've made a product that extracts non-sampled, non-aggregated data from Google Analytics I have learned a thing or two about the structure.

I makes sense that the data is populated via BigTable.
BT offers localization data awareness and map/reduce querying across n-nodes.

Distinct counts
(Whether a data service can provide distinct counts or not is a simple measure of flexibility of a data model - but it's typically also a measure of cost and performance)

Google Analytics is not built to do distinct counts even though GA can count users across almost any dimension - but it can't count e.g. Sessions per ga:pagePath?
How so...
Well they only register a session with the first pageView in a session.
This means that we can only count how many landingpages that have had a session.
We have no count for all the other 99% of pages on your site. :/

The reason for this is that Google made the choice NOT to count discount counts at all. It simply doesn't scale well economically when serving millions of sites for free.
They needed an approach where they could avoid counting distinct. Distinct count is all about sorting, grouping lists of ids for every cell in data intersection.

But...
Isn't it simple to count the distinct number of session on a ga:pagePath value?
I'll answer this in a bit

The User and data partitioning
The choice they made was to partition data on users (clientIds or userIds)
Because when they know that clientId/userId X is only present in a certain table in BT, they can run a map/reduce function that counts users and they don't have to be concerned that the same user is present in another dataset and be forced to store all clientIds/userIds in a list - group them - and then count them - distinct.
Since the current GA tracking script is called Universal Analytics they have to be able to count users correct. Especially when focusing on cross-device tracking.

OK, but how does this affect session count?
You have a set of users, each having multiple sets of sessions each having a list of page hits.
When counting within a specific session looking for a pagePaths, you will find the same page multiple times but you will not count the page more than once.
You need to write down you've already seen this page before. 
When you have traversed all pages within that session you need only count the session once per page. This procedure requires a state/memory. And since the counting process is probably done in parallel on the same server. You can't be sure that a specific session is handled by the same process. Which makes the counting even more memory consuming.
Google decided not to chase that rabit any longer and just ignore that the session count is wrong for pagePath and other hit scoped dimensions.

"Cube" storage
The reason I write "cube" is that I don't know exactly if they use traditional a OLAP cube structure, but I know they have up to 100 cubes populated for answering different dimension/metric combinations.

By isolation/grouping dimensions in smaller cubes, data won't explode exponentially like it would if they put all data in a single cube.
The drawback is that not all data combinations are allowed. Which we know is true.
E.g. ga:transactionId and ga:eventCategory can't be queried together.

By choosing this structure the dataset can scale well economical and performance-wise

Answer (score 1):

Many places and applications in the Google portfolio use the **MapReduce** algorithm for storage and processing of large quantities of data.

See the [Google Research Publications on MapReduce](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html) for further information and also have a look at [page 4](http://www.baselinemag.com/c/a/Infrastructure/How-Google-Works-1/4/) and [page 5](http://www.baselinemag.com/c/a/Infrastructure/How-Google-Works-1/5/) of [this](http://www.baselinemag.com/article2/0,1540,1985048,00.asp) Baseline article.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics runs on '**Mesa: Geo-Replicated, Near Real-Time, Scalable DataWarehousing**'.
https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/42851.pdf

"Mesa is a highly scalable analytic data warehousing systemthat stores critical measurement data related to Google’sInternet advertising business."