# Google Analytics API - Choice of Metric Affects Dimension Values Returned?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Good morning.  I've seen this behavior in the Google Analytics API, which as a SQL guy I find bizarre.  I'd like to get a list of all values for adContent, so I query `ga:adContent` and (because I must also select a metric, for no well-defined reason) `ga:organicSearches`.  It's in the same group (Campaign), so maybe it'll perform better back on the server.

I get one row: adContent is "(not set)", organicSearches is 516,674.  Huh, I guess adContent isn't being used.  But the marketing department swears that it is, and produce some convincing screen shots.

Later on, I arbitrarily change the metric to `ga:transactions`.  In the universe I woke up in, this should have absolutely no impact on anything, except the actual value returned in that column.  Instead, I get zillions of rows, with plausible values for `ga:adContent`.  The value for `ga:transactions` is sometimes zero, so it's not the case that GA was filtering for "metric > 0".

There are no filters in my query.  I did not change the date range between these two variants.  Can anyone tell me what's going on?  I expect the above queries to translate to something like this, which should return exactly the same number of rows:

```
SELECT adContent, SUM(organicSearches)
FROM Campaign
WHERE Date BETWEEN X AND Y
GROUP BY adContent

SELECT adContent, SUM(transactions)
FROM Campaign INNER JOIN ECommerce ON <something>
WHERE Date BETWEEN X AND Y
GROUP BY adContent
```

I realize that GA probably isn't using an ordinary RDMS on the back end, but surely 1 + 1 still equals 2 in any database!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition `ga:organicSearches` will almost never have any matches for `ga:adContent` (edge cases aside). `ga:adContent` is for the content of an advertisement, where `ga:organicSearches` is for organic search result visits within a session (like if you use Google multiple times within the same session to try to find something specific on a site). Don't use it for anything besides trying to measure that particular phenomenon.

Try not to use an SQL mindframe here; Google Analytics doesn't use SQL on the backend, so the notions you have of traditional relationships aren't applicable. IIRC, they use a few things, amongst them a [BigTable variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108322/google-analytics-database/2108500#2108500), which is a NoSQL-type database.

[From a Google Paper on BigTable from 2006](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flabs.google.com%2Fpapers%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf&ei=2ANcTf_-KoH6lwf6j_HiCQ&usg=AFQjCNHN6UZKpTHsquOhtbcjMa06GqDPQQ&sig2=gU0E7fDO0mYo0lokzBJlcA):

> We briefly describe two of the tables
>   used by Google Analytics. The raw
>   click table ( ̃200 TB) maintains a row
>   for each end-user session. The row
>   name is a tuple containing the
>   website’s name and the time at which
>   the session was created. This schema
>   ensures that sessions that visit the
>   same web site are contiguous, and that
>   they are sorted chronologically. This
>   table compresses to 14% of its
>   original size. The summary table ( ̃20
>   TB) contains various predefined
>   summaries for each website. This table
>   is generated from the raw click table
>   by periodically scheduled MapReduce
>   jobs. Each MapReduce job extracts
>   recent session data from the raw click
>   table. The overall system’s throughput
>   is limited by the throughput of GFS.
>   This table compresses to 29% of its
>   original size.

If you want the lowest common denominator for a metric for a list of all dimensions, use `ga:pageviews`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, yc.  That makes sense; I suppose I assumed that within a single group (Campaign) there would be no joining, and therefore no filtering unless I asked for it.  Thanks also for the LCD suggestion, that's sounds like exactly what I need for dimension-only queries.